Flask App with Docker Compose Fails to Connect to MongoDB: ServerSelectionTimeoutError
I'm developing a Flask application that uses MongoDB for storage, and I'm trying to dockerize the setup using Docker Compose. However, I'm encountering a ServerSelectionTimeoutError when the Flask app tries to connect to MongoDB. The error suggests that the app is attempting to connect to localhost:27017 instead of the MongoDB service defined in the Docker Compose file.
Here's the relevant part of my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: "mongodb://mongo:27017/mylibrary"

In my Flask app's config.py, I'm setting the MONGO_URI based on the environment variable:
class Config:
    MONGO_URI = os.environ.get('MONGODB_URI') or "mongodb://mongo:27017/mylibrary"


And in the Flask app (app/init.py), I'm using this configuration:
from flask import Flask
from .extensions import db
from .books.routes import api as books_api

def create_app(config_filename=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_filename)
    db.init_app(app)
    books_api.init_app(app)

    return app



Despite these settings, I'm getting the following error:
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused


I've tried debugging by printing the MONGO_URI in the Flask app, and it correctly shows mongodb://mongo:27017/mylibrary. I've also made sure to rebuild the Docker images and restart the containers after making changes to the configuration.
What might be causing the Flask app to attempt a connection to localhost instead of the MongoDB service defined in Docker Compose, and how can I resolve this issue?

is your mongodb container running? is mongodb container part of same network as you application? Make sue, there are no firewall rules or security groups blocking the connection. check your application as well as mongodb container logs.

Can you share more code where you are using pymongo?
I think pymongo is trying to use default client option, not using usr env config
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html

@KadeYoun I think theres no issue with pymongo, when i run flask outside docker but mongo and frontend inside docker it works fine

Do you mean flask at outside of docker not works, and
Flask inside of docker works fine?
Anyway, inside of docker you can use mongodb://mongo:27017 as a service
because of service name provided by docker network and compose.
And outside of Docker, if you are running flask app on same node, localhost:27017 can be work because docker is providing exposing port 27017:27017

version: '3.7'
services:
mongodb:
image: mongo:latest
#container_name: mongoDB-Cont //specifying container name
environment:
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
restart: always
ports:
- 27017:27017
volumes:
- mongodb_data_cont:/data/db
please take refrence  from above mention its work
